# WebStorm Git (git repository cannot be cloned to an existing directory)

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

В чем проблема? 
[image]

12:53:22 Created Git repository in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/workout_test

12:59:47 Update canceled

12:59:47 Can't update: no tracked branch
         No tracked branch configured for branch master.
         To make your branch track a remote branch call, for example,
         git branch --set-upstream master origin/master*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю вот это должен сработать:

```
git init
git remote add origin PATH/TO/REPO
git fetch
git checkout -t origin/master
```

Информация взята [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18999726/1330787).

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно удалить из **Parent Directory** в конце пути **test_theme_wp**, так же если существует эта папка на сервере её то же удалить.
**Parent Directory** - это родительская папка в которой мы будем находиться перед клонированием.
**Directory Name** - это имя папки которая будет создана в родительской категории в которую будет с клонирован текущий репозиторий.
 Перед клонированием если данная папка существует, то её необходимо удалить иначе шторм будет ругаться на неё.