# Как стянуть репозиторий в не пустую папку?

Tags: git, git-clone

Подготовил папку на сервере, тяну в неё удалённый репозиторий через `git clone` возникает ошибка:

> fatal: destination path '...' already exists and is not an empty
>   directory.

Там лежит папка со статикой, она мне нужна, можно мне как-то обойти эту ошибку? Типа `git clone --force` или ещё что-нибудь в этом роде сделать.

Comment: близко по смыслу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/647839/178576

Comment: @alexander barakin там нет решения вопроса в этом ответе

Comment: есть. конкретная ссылка на ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/533613/178576 // что вас побуждает считать, что этот ответ вам не подходит?

Answer (score 2):

Можете склонировать в пустую папку и потом перенести в папку со статикой, но тогда получается что статика попадет в сам репозиторий.

Чтобы исключить папку со статикой из контроля версий добавьте её в `.gitignore` файл который создайте в корневой папке, и напишите просто название папки, вот так:

```
static
```

Тогда репозиторий будет рядом с вашей папкой и она не будет отслеживаться системой контроля версий.